# Maintain the particular state in jquery accordian after postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I have the Problem to keep the active accordion  open when the li is clicked after the post-back of ASP.NET page.

here is the Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nav > li > a').click(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active') {
            $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
            $(this).next().slideToggle();
            $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });

});
```

Here is the Markup:

```
                            <ul id="nav">
                                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 a</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 b</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 c</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 a</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 b</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 a</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 b</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 c</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 d</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
                                    <ul>
                                       <li><a href="Facilitysoft_masterdetails.aspx?view=1">Site Master</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="Facilitysoft_masterdetails.aspx?view=2">Phase Master</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="Facilitysoft_masterdetails.aspx?view=3">Block Master</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="Facilitysoft_masterdetails.aspx?view=4">Subblock Master</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="Facilitysoft_masterdetails.aspx?view=5">Floor Master</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="Facilitysoft_masterdetails.aspx?view=6">Flat Master</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="Facilitysoft_masterdetails.aspx?view=7">Issue Master</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="Facilitysoft_masterdetails.aspx?view=8">Gym/Swim Master</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="Facilitysoft_masterdetails.aspx?view=9">Stock Master</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="Facilitysoft_masterdetails.aspx?view=10">Clubhouse Master</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
```

For eg: 
when i click the "Item 4"  and then click the "clubhouse master" that particular aspx page is coming after that accordion is collapsible and  need to maintain that particular state.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that after a postback the HTML is rendered back to its default state.. This is equivalent to a page refresh in this case which the server remembers..

So the option you have here is to handle this in the endRequest handler which is fired after a postback ends..

```
$(function() {
     PostBack();

     Sys.WenForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(PostBack);
});

function PostBack(){
     // You need to save the state of the Accordion
     // just before the postback
     // and handle it here..
     // Maybe store it in a hiddenField 
     // and retrieve it to change the settings..
}
```

Comment: Try this approach http://www.isolutionteam.co.uk/retain-jquery-accordion-current-index-across-the-asp-net-post-back/

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. i.e. wanted to save the state of accordian in case of GET requests. In my master template, wrote switch case of pages

```
if (strPage.EndsWith("page1.aspx")
                || strPage.EndsWith("page2.aspx"))

                this.hdnfldtset.Value="ELS";
            else if (strPage.EndsWith("page3.aspx")                
                || strPage.EndsWith("page4.aspx")

                this.hdnfldtset.Value="CMS";
```

Then, in javascript of master page, read this hidden value and open/close appropriate accordian section. This will work when the items you have use GET of the page like simple . That was the case in my application. If in your case, it is postback, then you can use hidden field to set and retrieve with javascript.